# Rails associations and Postgres aggregate functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm at a loss with trying to successfully call an associated column whilst creating an aggregate function in Postgres using Rails 5.2. I keep getting the following error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "items.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I've tried a couple of solutions such as adding the `items.name` column to my group clause, but it returns an undesirable result due to the belongs_to/has_many association between `sale_selections: :item`.

I have also tried using `DISTINCT ON (sale_selections.id) sale_selections.id, items.name, etc`. But this give me the same error result.

Is it possible to include a column in a select method without needing to add it to the group clause and still have the ability to reference it? Or do I need to find another solution?

**My Query**

```
@search = Sale.joins(sale_selections: :item)
.select('sale_selections.id, items.name, AVG(sale.price) as price)
.group('sale_selections.id').where('sale.price IS NOT NULL')
```

**My view**

```
<% @search.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.name %> <br />
  <%= s.sale %>
<% end %>
```

**Model associations**

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sale_selections, dependent: :destroy
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sale_selections
end

class SaleSelection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :Sale
  belongs_to :Item
end
```

**Update**

Doing the following query does not provide correct results due to the association between `sale_selections: :item`.

```
@search = Sale.joins(sale_selections: :item)
.select('items.id, items.name, AVG(sale.price) as price)
.group('items.id').where('sale.price IS NOT NULL')
```

It provides the same average price for all items in the query, instead of the correct values that grouping by `sale_selections.id` provides.

**Sale table**

```
| id | price |
| 1  |  2.50 |
| 2  |  1.50 |
| 3  |  1.30 |
```

**Item table**

```
| id |   name  |
| 1  |   Apple |
| 2  |  Banana |
```

**Sale Selections table**

```
| id | sale_id | item_id |
| 1  |   1     |    1    |
| 2  |   2     |    2    |
| 2  |   3     |    2    |
```

So my average result for apple should be 2.50 and Banana should be 1.40. But if I add the `item.name` to the group method I get 1.77 displayed both in Apple and Banana.

Comment: Generally speaking, PostgreSQL requires all selected columns to be part of the "group by" or an aggregate function.  In this case, you simply need to add the name to the "group by".  It's correct to do it that way, and it will give you the desired result.  If it doesn't give the desired result, it's likely that your data model is wrong.  Please include specifics.

Comment: can you upload your model structure (Sale, SaleSelection, Item) and how you relate them

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MichaelChaney. The problem with adding items.name to the group is that items has many sale_selections and it groups by each sale_selections.id and each items.name which kind of doubles the results and the average calculations don't match. When grouping by sale_selections.id I get the right result, but just can't reference the item name at all.

Comment: I have updated the question with my model associations.

Comment: Please provide data example and describe what you're trying to calculate

Comment: Thanks @Vasfed. I've added the db schema and some data. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: You can put more than one column in the group. 
`@search = Sale.joins(sale_selections: :item)
.select('items.id, items.name, AVG(sale.price) as price)
.group('items.id, sale_selections.id').where('sale.price IS NOT NULL')`

Comment: Thanks Mike. Adding items.name to the group method doesn’t provide the desired result.

Comment: When you run this in console, it will show the generated SQL statement.  Paste that in as well.

Answer (score 0):

Selected columns need to be at least functionally dependent on groupped by ones (and only be the groupped ones and aggregate functions in strict mode).

Assuming you're trying to calculate average sale price for each item, try:

```
Item.select("items.id, items.name, AVG(sales.price) as average_sale_price").
  joins(sale_selections: :sale).
  where("sales.price is not null").
  group("items.id")
```

**Update. Runnable example:**

```
require "bundler/inline"
gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem "activerecord", "5.2.2.1"
  gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.6"
end

require "active_record"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "logger"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table(:items, force: true){|t| t.string  :name }
  create_table(:sales, force: true) {|t| t.decimal :price }
  create_table :sale_selections, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :sale_id
    t.integer :item_id
  end
end

class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sale_selections, dependent: :destroy
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sale_selections
end

class SaleSelection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sale
  belongs_to :item
end

class SomeTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_stuff
    apple, banana = %w[Apple Banana].map{|i| Item.create! name: i}
    [apple, banana, banana].zip([2.5, 1.5, 1.3]).each{|item, price|
      SaleSelection.create item:item, sale: Sale.create(price: price)
    }

    res = Item.select("items.id, items.name, AVG(sales.price) as average_sale_price").
      joins(sale_selections: :sale).
      where("sales.price is not null").
      group("items.id")

    res.each{|r| puts "#{r.name} avg is #{r.average_sale_price}" }

    avg = res.map{|r| [r.id, r.average_sale_price]}.to_h
    assert_equal 1.4, avg[banana.id]
    assert_equal 2.5, avg[apple.id]
  end
end
```

Comment: This method provides an average of all items and displays it for each item.name. So all records have the same result. For example I have two items name Apple and Banana. The average for apples should be $0.50 (2 items sold) and Bananas are $1.00 (1 item sold). The above results gives me $0.50 for both items as it seem to be average to total of all items then average by 3.

Comment: @DollarChills added runnable test - the code indeed produce results that you expect in updated question